# Tail call optimization in Racket

Tags: garbage-collection, scheme, racket, tail-call-optimization

I was doing SICP [exercise 2.28](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_thm_2.28) and stumbled upon a strange behaviour of the following code:

```
(define (fringe tree)
  (cond
    ((null? tree) '())
    ((not (pair? tree)) (list tree))
    (else (append (fringe (car tree)) (fringe (cdr tree))))))

(define (fringe-tail tree)
  (define (fringe-iter tree result)
    (cond
      ((null? tree) result)
      ((not (pair? tree)) (list tree))
      (else (fringe-iter (cdr tree) (append result (fringe-tail (car tree)))))))
  (fringe-iter tree '()))

(define x (make-list (expt 10 4) 4))
(time (fringe x))
(time (fringe-tail x))
```

Ordinary `fringe` runs much faster than its iterative version `fringe-tail`:

```
cpu time: 4 real time: 2 gc time: 0
```

vs.

```
cpu time: 1063 real time: 1071 gc time: 191
```

It looks like `fringe` was optimized into loop and avoids any allocations, while `fringe-tail` runs much slower and spends time creating and destroying objects.

Can anyone explain this to me?
(Just in case I'm using racket 5.2.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you replace the last clause with:

```
(else (fringe-iter (cdr tree) (append (fringe-tail (car tree)) result)))
```

then they run at the same speed for that input, and the tail-recursive version is faster for larger input.

The problem is that you're `append`ing the much longer list for the `cdr` on to the front, which traverses and allocates much more than the naive version, which appends the fringe of  the `car` on to the front.

Answer (score 4):

The given code has applications in non-tail position, so the function is not iterative, despite its name.  :)

Try this:

```
(define (fringe-tail tree)
  (define (iter tree k)
    (cond
      [(null? tree)
       (k '())]
      [(not (pair? tree)) 
       (k (list tree))]
      [else
       (iter (car tree)
             (lambda (v1)
               (iter (cdr tree)
                     (lambda (v2)
                       (k (append v1 v2))))))]))
  (iter tree (lambda (a-fringe) a-fringe)))
```

However, it still uses *append* which is as expensive as the length of its first argument.  Certain degenerate inputs into *fringe* and *fringe-tail* will cause a lot of computational suffering.

Let's give an example of such degenerate inputs:

```
(define (build-evil-struct n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (list 0)
      (list (list (build-evil-struct (sub1 n)))
            (build-evil-struct (sub1 n))
            (list n))))

(define evil-struct (build-evil-struct 20))
```

When applied to both *fringe* and *fringe-iter*, you'll see very bad performance: I observe seconds of compute time on my own system for *fringe* and *fringe-tail*.  These tests were run under DrRacket with debugging disabled.  If you enable debugging, your numbers will be significantly different.

```
> (time (void (fringe evil-struct)))
cpu time: 2600 real time: 2602 gc time: 1212

> (time (void (fringe-tail evil-struct)))
cpu time: 4156 real time: 4155 gc time: 2740
```

With both of these, the use of *append* is what makes these susceptible to certain degenerate inputs.  If we write an accumulating version of *fringe*, we can eliminate that cost, since we then get to use the constant-time *cons* operation:

```
(define (fringe/acc tree)
  (define (iter tree acc)
    (cond [(null? tree)
           acc]
          [(not (pair? tree))
           (cons tree acc)]
          [else
           (iter (car tree) (iter (cdr tree) acc))]))
  (iter tree '()))
```

Let's look at the performance of fringe/acc on this structure:

```
> (time (void (fringe/acc evil-struct)))
cpu time: 272 real time: 274 gc time: 92
```

Much better!  And it's a straightforward matter to turn all the calls here to tail calls.

```
(define (fringe/acc/tail tree)
  (define (iter tree acc k)
    (cond [(null? tree)
           (k acc)]
          [(not (pair? tree))
           (k (cons tree acc))]
          [else
           (iter (cdr tree) acc
                 (lambda (v1)
                   (iter (car tree) v1 k)))]))
  (iter tree '() (lambda (v) v)))

> (time (void (fringe/acc/tail evil-struct)))
cpu time: 488 real time: 488 gc time: 280
```

Racket's implementation of the stack is, in this particular case, a bit faster than our reified stack we're representing in the continuations, so *fringe/acc* is faster than *fringe/acc/tail*.  Still, both of these are significantly better than *fringe* because they avoid *append*.

All this being said: this function is already built-into Racket as the [*flatten*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/list..rkt%29._flatten%29%29) function!  So you might as well just use that if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.  :)

Comment: Have you tried out your fully-tail-recursive version?  Is it faster on the example the question gives?

Comment: Added some performance numbers on a slightly more complicated tree.